# obtener contenido de <p> para dar valor a una variable php

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un panel de administración con Modals, necesito obtener la id para cambiar los registros en la base de datos, he optado por dar valor a un párrafo a partir del click en el botón de editar, sin embargo no consigo obtener el valor, me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
>  in C:\wamp\www\
> ```

El código es el siguiente...

```
$id = ".$('.sliderId').html().val().";
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','360');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes_slider WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

El slider a cambiar tiene el id: `<p id='sliderId'>1</p>`

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Entiendo que deberás obtener el valor mediante jQuery o JS, pero no directamente asignándolo a una variable php, así no se procesa js del modo que lo intentas.

Comment: Gracias por responder  jonilgz, el tema es que al final necesito dar a esa variable $id el contenido de <p>

Comment: No es el planteamiento correcto. Tendrías que capturar el valor en el evento clic y enviarlo vía "AJAX" al script que procesará el valor y hará los cambios en base de datos.

Comment: Exactamente como han comentado los compañeros. Esto `$id = ".$('.sliderId').html().val().";` es un claro intento de **mezcla** de código jQuery con código PHP. Ahí el valor de `$id` es este: `.$('.sliderId').html().val().`, eso funciona en jQuery, pero no en PHP. Es en jQuery donde debes obtener ese valor y pasarlo a PHP vía Ajax (si estás en otro archivo PHP, y si estás en el mismo, debes usar jQuery para obtener el valor). En cuanto a la base de datos, usa consultas preparadas, para que no te lleves una desagradable sorpresa cualquier día de estos.

Comment: Gracias por responder Muriano, entiendo que no es un planteamiento habitual pero Ajax me es desconocido y estoy más seguro en Php, como le he dicho a jonilgz lo único que necesitaría para que todo funcionase es poder asignarle el valor a la variable $id, un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta A. Cedano, entonces la solución es pasarlo a Php vía Ajax, me pondré manos a la obra, lo que no quería era tener que cambiar todo el código para que funcionase con Ajax.

Comment: Al usar Ajax no estás haciendo nada anormal, sino todo lo contrario... es la forma correcta de proceder. Además, Ajax te permite obtener datos del servidor y presentarlos en tu página actual sin moverte de ella, sin tener que refrescarla, etc. Descubrir Ajax no es otra cosa que descubrir algo maravilloso. Aquí en SO hay varios ejemplos de peticiones Ajax, inspírate en uno que esté bien elaborado.

Comment: Soy consciente que Ajax tiene más potencial, pero al haberlo planteado desde un principio con php la cosa se complicaba... Agradezco las observaciones, me familizaré con Ajax un saludo!

Comment: Entiende que PHP es un lenguaje de servidor. Cualquier interacción que ocurra en el navegador es desconocida para él. Cualquier intento de interacción PHP - JAVASCRIPT que no pase por AJAX, simplemente no funcionará. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Pero cómo estás llenando el contenido de `sliderId`? Muéstranos que hay más arriba en el código. Además, `$('.sliderId').html().val();` es una sintaxis incorrecta incluso para jQuery, puesto que el HTML puro de un elemento es simplemente texto y no tiene método `val`.

Comment: Sisi entiendo lo que quieres decir Muriano, muchas gracias por las observaciones

Comment: No añadas código en los comentarios, es difícil de leer y no se indexa. Si tienes nueva información, pulsa en el botón de [edit] para añadirla a la pregunta.

Comment: Si el valor de sliderID siempre es `$row[0]` entonces usa esa variable en tu PHP directamente.

Por otro lado, el selector correcto sería `$('#slideriD')` aunque eso para tu problema es irrelevante

Comment: Si tienes varias filas, y cada fila puede abrir un modal, y cada modal debe mostrar un contenido diferente, entonces necesariamente debes usar ajax para enviar el ID de la fila correspondiente a tu backend.

Comment: Guillermo, borra los comentarios obsoletos. si son informacion util, añáde las explicacion en la pregunta editandola. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Como no disponemos del código completo, te dejo una aproximación:

> Fichero HTML (Ej. index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='sliderId'>Hola</p> 
        <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>

        <!-- JS CODE -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#enviar").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "script.php",
                    data: { id: $('#sliderId').text() }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                  alert( "Devolución de PHP: " + msg );
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Fichero PHP (Ej. script.php):

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
//Código probado hasta aquí, lo consiguiente es trabajar el PHP
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','360');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes_slider WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

Una vez ejecutado, saldrá un alert con el resultado que PHP devuelve, en este caso simplemente hacemos un echo del valor recibido (contenido del div sliderId).

Obviamente el código es una muestra, y deberás adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Entiende que es una base sobre la cual puedas trabajar. Finaliza tu PHP con un echo que devuelva el estado de la petición a AJAX (será lo que se muestre en el alert).

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo jonilgz, en cuanto lo tenga comento! Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Esta solución tiene al menos un par de problemas: 1) no atiende el error mostrado en la pregunta (que es de MySQL y no de JavaScript/PHP) y que seguirá ocurriendo; 2) el código presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad (puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL) y no debería ser usado en entornos de producción.

Comment: La pregunta no es sobre MySQL, la pregunta es como enviar el parámetro que contiene un elemento P, a PHP. Si se usa esta solución, el error quedará solventado, asignando la ID a la variable que es la raiz del problema. Se le ofrece una solución mediante AJAX, y además se comenta que el consiguente queda de su cuenta, pues el usuario dice que si se entiende en PHP, sobre la seguridad el código puede no estar terminado faltando filtrar datos etc.